How to fix "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error?
Getting the error in the title when trying to run a command on powershell that enables non admin for Regression Suite Automation Tool.
the command is the 2nd part of 2 commands what have to be ran to allow RSAT tool - non admin to work as detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/perf-test/rsat/rsat-configure-nonadmin.
I have to add my own bit of the command in due to policies in place in the business but this worked last month, this now doesn't appear to work though an prompts me with the error in the title and no further information or messages.
Also, I have checked this in the ISE and there is nothing for this error in the script.
C:\Program Files\Regression Suite Automation Tool\Enable non admin> powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass .\Enable-non-admin-user.ps1 "enable" "DomainName\Username" "AA805E60D7987594AEF45279D4980BAAED08302D"
enter image description here

Without seeing the contents of the script, my best guess would be that the certificate thumbprint cannot be resolved, so the script eventually calls something like $cert.SomeMethod(), where $cert happens to contain $null. Try swapping the order of the username and thumbprint

I will try shortly but the parameters set in place appear to be:
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $action,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $user,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $thumbprint
)

You can't.  Without the code there's no way to see what's wrong.
